# Как выбрать элемент если он совпадает со списком?

Tags: python, selenium

```
for i in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="translators-list"]/li'):
    if i.text == 'TVShows' or 'Кубик в Кубе (Kubik³) (реж. версия)' or 'Дубляж':
        i.click()
        break
```

На сайте есть озвучки, мне нужно чтобы драйвер выбрал подходящую из 'TVShows' or 'Кубик в Кубе (Kubik³) (реж. версия)' or 'Дубляж', но печему-то не работает, не могу понять почему. + Если выбрал озвучку нужно закончить цикл и продолжить код дальше.

Comment: if i.text in ['TVShows', 'Кубик в Кубе (Kubik³) (реж. версия)', 'Дубляж'] a так?

Answer (score 0):

Раньше сталкивался с похожей проблемой, мне помог такой вариант:

```
for i in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="translators-list"]/li'):
    if i.text == 'TVShows' or i.text =='Кубик в Кубе (Kubik³) (реж. версия)' or i.text =='Дубляж':
        i.click()
        break
```